# ASP NET Core clean architecture

Tags: asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I've always written everything on one project and now that I'm working on another project it has started to grow. I'm slowly feeling more and more confused by what I wrote myself. That's why I started looking for and finding the principles of clean architecture. I think I already know what it is, but I have a question about it:
The Infrastructure project is for data contact, and the Core project is for what? And what are the other frequently used project types (such as Core and Infrastructure) and what are they for?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures

Comment: I read this, but I think there are more project types such as Infrastructure. Also, it says Core has entities, so Infrastructure provides data access and creates migrations based on entities included in Core? I think the projects should be a bit more independent. That is why I am asking this question.

Comment: Take a look at Rob C Martin's blog : https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

Answer (score 0):

The Core project typically contains you business models (e.g EFCore entities), interfaces, value objects etc. You have to make sure that your core project does not depend on any of other projects, such as Infrastructure, Web etc. You will commonly need Web project as well. This project contains presentation layer, it's Views/Controllers and other asp.net core related stuff, if you work on asp net core mvc/web api project. David Osborne's answer directs you to a book I suggest you to take a look at as well.
You can also watch the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkmvnjypENw) from the book author about clean arch in asp.net core 6.

Comment: Ok, so if I have a Handler that handles some controller logic (and also calls validators that use database for example) should I put it on Core or on the Web? Or maybe create another Web.Controllers.Handlers project? In short, what an example structure of a web project should look like with controllers that call Handlers that call other things to handle, such as validators that verify the data received in the Controller for, inter alia, compliance with those in the database (e.g. verifying the given password with hash in database)?